# Import data in Pubnub

Tags: android, database, publish-subscribe, pubnub

Is there any way to import data from server in pubnub.I have an chat application in which we are using google app engine back end now I want to implement pubnub api for chat but all previous chat saved on my server database.Please let me know if there is any way to import previous data in pubnub db.

Comment: We received your request in support and will address it there.

Comment: Thanks For reverting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Import Data into PubNub Storage

You can import your messages from your current database using a [*publish timetoken override* (PTTO)](https://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/122/how-to-overwrite-a-message-in-pubnub-storage-history).

This means you will implement a script to read data from your current message data store and publish them one by one into PubNub channels.

> NOTE: You have to contact your customer success manager (via PubNub Support) to enable the `no_rep` flag on your keys.